# ASP.NET Increase upload max size for specific API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

This is ASP.NET WebForm 4.7 with API.

Application accepts many document uploads in many areas. For security web.config was set up for max 50MB, which works fine.

```
<requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
</requestFiltering>
```

We now need to upload with a dedicated API video files up to 500MB.

I would have preferred to keep the default upload limit to 50MB for the entire application but allow 500MB+ for this dedicated API.
I moved the API file in a sub folder of /Controllers and added a new web.config in the sub folder.
New web.config has just one setting overruling root web.config.

API is still routed, but web.config beside it has now effect. (I knew this was a long shot...)

Any Idea how this could be achieved?